# JS, can't change checkbox .checked on button click

Tags: javascript, html

This snippet works, the classes toggle on and off.

```js
function click_filter(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
        return false;
    }
    let button =
        event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "button"
            ? event.target
            : event.target.parentNode;
    let checkbox = button.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    let icon = button.querySelector("i");

    // trying to debug
    console.log("Click on filter ", checkbox.value);
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        console.log("Was checked", checkbox.checked);
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
        console.log("Has been unchecked", checkbox.checked);
    } else {
        console.log("Was unchecked", checkbox.checked);
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
        console.log("Has been checked", checkbox.checked);
    }
    // trying to debug

    // usual code
    //checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked

    button.classList.toggle("btn-primary", checkbox.checked);
    button.classList.toggle("active", checkbox.checked);

    // toggle classes "fa-check-square" and "fa-square"  in icon
    icon.classList.toggle("fa-check-square", checkbox.checked);
    icon.classList.toggle("fa-square", !checkbox.checked);
}


let filters = document.querySelectorAll(".btn[data-toggle=buttons]");

filters.forEach(filter => {
        filter.addEventListener('click', click_filter);
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mb-3">
        <span class="button-checkbox">
            <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
                <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="match" name="filters">
                <i class="far fa-square"></i>
                match
            </button>
        </span>
        <span class="button-checkbox">
            <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
                <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="mismatch" name="filters">
                <i class="far fa-square"></i>
                mismatch
            </button>
        </span>
        <span class="button-checkbox">
            <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
                <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="notfound" name="filters">
                <i class="far fa-square"></i>
                notfound
            </button>
        </span>
        <span class="button-checkbox">
            <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
                <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="incomplete-payment" name="filters">
                <i class="far fa-square"></i>
                incomplete-payment
            </button>
        </span>
        <span class="button-checkbox">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
                <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="all" name="filters">
                <i class="far fa-square"></i>
                all
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

However, for some reason, in my environment it doesn't work.
I get

```
Click on filter  notfound
Was unchecked false
Has been checked true
Click on filter  notfound
Was unchecked false
Has been checked true
Click on filter  notfound
Was unchecked false
Has been checked true
```

- The `click_filter` function is defined in `utils.js`
- The `filters` querySelector is defined in `globals.js`
- Then in `main.js` I have this:

```
import {
    filters,
} from './globals.js';
import {
    click_filter
} from './utils.js';

$(document).ready(main);

function main() {
    filters.forEach(filter => {
        filter.addEventListener('click', click_filter);
    });
}
```

Is that the problem? Using modules? I tried using `checkbox.click()` instead of `checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked` and it seemed to work, I had to return if `event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input"` to avoid double firing the event.

Comment: why not to debug step-by-step, why not to remove modules one-by-one and thus find the culprit?

Comment: There's no modules to remove, what's at the end of the question is pretty much all there is. no other code touches any checkbox or checked attribute.

Comment: i meant move your code from modules one-by-one to see whether the problem is in a module

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you are going with this however I did make a couple of assumptions.

Here I simplified the code a bit to toggle the classes and the checked value.  I also added a different data value to the `all` making the assumption you wanted to toggle on/off all of the others based on this value - I leveraged the same `toggleMe` to set its value also by just calling that with the `all` click event element once I set up its value.

I added the font awesome since you seemed to want that visual instead of "checkboxes" which makes sense so you can style it a bit - note how I changed the size with CSS to clearly show this in use with a `parent` class on the wrapper.

Note how I compare the filters length vs the total number and then check the `all` when they match OR simply set the filters to match the state of the `all` checkbox when `all` is clicked.

```js
let filters = document.querySelectorAll(".btn[data-toggle='buttons']");
let allBtn = document.querySelector(".btn[data-toggle='buttons-all']");

function toggleMe(el, shouldCheck) {
  const checkbox = el.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
  const icon = el.querySelector("i.icon");
  checkbox.checked = shouldCheck;
  el.classList.toggle('btn-primary', shouldCheck);
  el.classList.toggle('active', shouldCheck);
  icon.classList.toggle('fa-check-square', shouldCheck);
  icon.classList.toggle('fa-square', !shouldCheck);
}

function handleClick(event) {
  const button = event.currentTarget;
  const checkbox = button.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
  const icon = button.querySelector("i.icon");
  const shouldCheck = !checkbox.checked;
  checkbox.checked = shouldCheck;
  toggleMe(button, shouldCheck);
  let checkFilters = [...filters].filter(filter => {
    return filter.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").checked;
  });
  const shouldCheckAll = checkFilters.length == [...filters].length;
  toggleMe(allBtn, shouldCheckAll);
}

function handleAllClick(event) {
  const all = event.currentTarget;
  const checkbox = all.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']");
  const isChecked = checkbox.checked;
  filters.forEach(filter => {
    filter.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']").checked = isChecked;
    filter.click();
  });
  toggleMe(all, !isChecked);
}

allBtn.addEventListener('click', handleAllClick);

filters.forEach(filter => {
  filter.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```css
.body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.parent * {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="mb-3 parent">
  <span class="button-checkbox ">
    <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
      <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="match" name="filters" />
      <i class="icon far fa-square align-middle"></i>
     <span class="align-middle">match</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
      <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="mismatch" name="filters" />
      <i class="icon far fa-square align-middle"></i>
      <span class="align-middle">mismatch</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
    <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="notfound" name="filters" />
    <i class="icon far fa-square align-middle"></i>
   <span class="align-middle">notfound</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn active" data-toggle="buttons" data-color="primary">
      <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="incomplete-payment" name="filters" />
        <i class="icon far fa-square align-middle"></i>
        <span class="align-middle">incomplete-payment</span>
  </button>
  </span>
  <span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="buttons-all" data-color="primary">
      <input class="form-check-input hidden" type="checkbox" value="all" name="filters" />
      <i class="icon far fa-square align-middle"></i>
     <span class="align-middle">all</span>
  </button>
  </span>
</div>
```